# Perforce output states "<some-depot-file-path> - deleted as <some-local-file-path>

Tags: synchronization, perforce

I have executed a command line 
`p4 sync <local-directory-path` 

I have a large number of files under the depot directory mapped with my perforce client directory. However, during this operation. I receive the info text:

> 'depot-path' - deleted as 'local-dir-path'

This happens for a couple of files. Can I know what does this mean? I tried the p4 documentation. But, it helps me with *nothing*.

I would much appreciate the response. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The message isn't trying to trick you -- the local file 'local-dir-path' was deleted from the workspace.  This is most likely because the corresponding depot file 'depot-path' was deleted from the depot.

You can confirm this by running:

```
p4 filelog 'depot-path'
```

which (I expect) will show you the history of that file, with the latest revision being a "delete".

There are other reasons that sync might delete a file, such as that you specified a nonexistent revision, or unmapped the file from the workspace, but you didn't mention doing either of those things so I assume it's simply that the file was deleted.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found that there was some issue with my perforce settings. :) I reset my my perforce settings to get rid of it and logging in again.